# Java programing, how do i make an object return a value without calling a function?

Tags: java

for the following problem:

```
fraction r1=new(1,2)
system.out.println(r1)
```

OUTPUT:

```
1/2
```

Does anyone know of a way to force the object to return a specific string rather than calling the object.toString() function and avoiding the output of something like class.fraction@xxxxx.

Comment: Implement `toString()` in the Fraction class.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Java - How to create a println/print method for a custom class](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8001664/java-how-to-create-a-println-print-method-for-a-custom-class)

Answer (score 6):

When you call `System.out.print(o)` in Java, the `toString()` method of `o` is automatically called. Overwite this method in your `fraction` class and you should be good to go.

Answer (score 3):

You can always override `toString()`:

```
@Override
public String toString(){
  return "This Object";
}
```

All Classes in the Java Platform are Descendants of Object, which is why any object of any class (even the ones you create) has access to Object's `toString()` method defined as follows:

```
public String toString(){
  getClass().getName() + '@' + Integer.toHexString(hashCode());
}
```

`toString()` gets called by default when you call `System.out.println()` but its just a regular inherited method and there is nothing stopping you from freely overriding it.

See [this explanation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/subclasses.html) on Oracle's website.

Answer (score 1):

Override `Object.toString()` in your `Fraction` class

```
public class Fraction {

    private int numerator;
    private int denominator;

    public Fraction(int n, int d) {
        this.numerator = n;
        this.denominator = d;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        // String representation of Fraction
        return numerator + "/" + denominator;
    }
}
```

`toString()` is one of the few methods (like `equals()`, `hashCode()` etc.) that gets ***called implicitly*** under certain programmatic situations like (just naming a few)

- printing an object using `println()`
- printing a `Collection` of objects *(`toString()` is invoked on all the elements)*
- concatenation with a String *(like `strObj = "My obj as string is " + myObj;`)*