# Java - get garbled result(List) from MySQL

Tags: java, mysql, arraylist

The result should be like `[1,2,3,4]`, 
but i get garbled result like this

> ```
> [com.test.db.Network@383c7b61, com.test.db.Network@7f87898,
>  com.test.db.Network@6b93f47a, com.test.db.Network@50fb09cc]
> ```

Below is my related class

```
private static void doLocationList(PrintWriter responseOut) throws Exception
{
//---testing show network ID list
int x=0;
Network network = new Network();
responseOut.println("this is I: " +network.getNetworkID(x));

......
}
```

This is from another class

```
public static List<Network> getNetworkID(int networkID) throws Exception
{
List<Network> idList = new ArrayList<Network>();
Connection conn = getConnection();
PreparedStatement Statement = conn.prepareStatement("Select id from network");
ResultSet result = Statement.executeQuery();
    while(result.next()) {
        Network network = new Network();
        network.setId(result.getInt("id"));
        idList.add(network);
    }

return idList;
}
```

Any idea? Please help.

Comment: Why should the result be like this `[1,2,3,4]`?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Java - How to create a println/print method for a custom class](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8001664/java-how-to-create-a-println-print-method-for-a-custom-class)

Comment: Because the "select id from network" (in MySQL) will get 1,2,3,4.. So i want to get back the array numbers.

Comment: That gets numbers, but that's not what you're printing. You're printing a `List<Network>`.

Comment: I'm not sure the way i get the array number is correct or not, i just want to get result like [1,2,3,4]. The List<Network> should be change to String or something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to print the list of objects directly, you need to override the `toString()` method in the `Network` class and specify how to print the values when an object of this class is printed directly.

The default `toString()` method is as shown in [Object class docs.](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#toString%28%29) Have a look at [this post about toString()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3615721/how-to-use-the-tostring-method-in-java)