# Return List items as String with Lambda

Tags: java, lambda, java-8

Hello so far this is what i have done

```
class Ideone{

    public static void main (String[] args) throws java.lang.Exception{

        Person p1 = new Person("person1");
        Person p2 = new Person("person1");
        Person [] array = new Person[]{p1, p2};

        String name_to_test = "person1";

        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(Arrays.stream(array).filter(x -> x.name.equals(name_to_test)).toArray()));

    }
}

class Person{

    public String name;

    public Person(String name){
        this.name = name;
    }

}
```

but i get

[Person@1ab7765, Person@128cdfa] while i want to return them by the same name which i filter them.

Any ideas?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to create a println/print method for a custom class](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8001664/how-to-create-a-println-print-method-for-a-custom-class)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should `map()` every filtered `Person` to its corresponding name:

```
Arrays.stream(array)
      .map(Person::getName)
      .filter(name_to_test::equals)
      .toArray();
```

Of course, you have to make sure that there is a getter method for `name` in `Person`:

```
class Person {
    public String name;

    public Person(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }
}
```

Comment: That's nice but i specifically made the variable public to test it without getName function.

Comment: Then, instead of `Person::getName`, you can use `x -> x.name`

Comment: Not very convincing. Clearly the OP does not know about `Object.toString`, so if you want him to learn something... BTW this is a duplicate and should be closed as such

Comment: @Dici Indeed i was missing the toString solution and i'm happy to get it under my belt. Althought this solution it's what i was looking for when i originally made the post, so it's hard for me to overlook his help.

Comment: Better to map first, then filter. This way you can even use `.filter(name_to_test::equals)`!

Comment: @TagirValeev, true! I updated the answer accordingly. Thanks:)

Comment: It's not so clear though why the OP wants to have an array of several equal names...

Comment: @TagirValeev liked your suggestions for `.filter(name_to_test::equals)` very much i.e. use of method reference as Predicates.

Answer (score 2):

You can `@Override` the `Object#toString()` method in your `Person` objects to print their names instead.

This will display their `name` property when you print out the array.

The `[class]@[hash]` notation is the default `Object#toString()` representation of objects when not overridden.

Answer (score 1):

You have missed to override `toString` method in class.

```
class Person{

    public String name;

    public Person(String name){
        this.name = name;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Person{" +
                "name='" + name + '\'' +
                '}';
    }
}
```

Now the output is: `[Person{name='person1'}, Person{name='person1'}]`